# std::find is not working with istream_iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I am trying to find an element in a range spanned by `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` using `std::find`. The code does not compile, spitting out an error about template type deduction failure

> error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::istream_iterator >&, std::istream_iterator >&, std::__cxx11::string&)'
>        auto it = std::find(is, end, token);
>
> note: candidate: template typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, const _CharT2&)
>        find(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __first,
>
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

However, using [the implementation of `std::find` from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (a straightforward implementation) makes the code compilable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

// implementation of std::find from cppreference.com
template<class InputIt, class T>
InputIt find(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}

int main() 
{
    std::istringstream ss("this is a test");
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> is(ss);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;

    std::string token = "test";
    auto it = find(is, end, token); // put std::find here and it won't compile
    (it != end) ? std::cout << "Found\n" : std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Does any one know what's wrong with `std::find` and `istream_iterator`s? I though the requirements on `std::find` are pretty basic: the iterator should be an InputIterator, which `istream_iterator` is.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <algorithm>`.  works now: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63d8d55d5839d2d1

Comment: compiles and works fine for me without the custom find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> no matching function for call to 'find'

Well, indeed. You did not bring `std::find` into scope by typing the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: This was completely stupid from my part... Thanks! I was busy of understanding the template error message instead... darn. Voting to close the question.

Comment: The funky thing is that `std::find` seems to have some overload outside algorithm. Otherwise the error should have been less verbose, like: `error: 'find' is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: @vsoftco: Yeah, it's a forward/friendship declaration of the specialisation in [`<streambuf>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01048_source.html)